# PhpStorm - switch recent files by clicking side mouse button

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, shortcut

When I switch between two recent editor tabs I use <kbd>Ctrl + Tab</kbd> shortcut. This feature of editor navigation called "switcher" in PhpStorm (Settings -> Keymap -> Other -> Switcher 'recent files' actions).
"Switcher" fast shows list of recent files and immediately AUTOCLOSE after short-cut keys releases up.

But when I try to set up mouse side key on this function, "switcher" window shows and NOT closes on mouse button up! Is there a way to set up mouse side key to fast switch RECENT tabs? (in natural order tabs switch works good by mouse keys, but not in recent order)

*I hope you understand what I need, sorry for my eng*

Comment: You are trying to change a keyboard shortcut, can you add the actual key that you are assigning to the "mouse side key"

Comment: @Luuk It is possible to add shortcuts to mouse buttons and I have common mouse with useful side buttons (forward - backward usually)

Comment: The question was, Which [key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6aCI.png) did you actually assign to the "mouse side key" (In this screenshot `Ctrl + Shift + / `)

Comment: @Luuk I'm trying to use the PhpStorm capabilities only. No have mouse driver...
[add mouse shortcut](https://i.imgur.com/LdxvYUm.png) and got this "[Button 4 click](https://i.imgur.com/RbLu0bg.png)" together with original keyboard shortcut. But it doesn't work the same.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, if it worked the way you want it to work, it wouldn't be possible to switch to any file apart from the previous one, as Switcher would open and close immediately.
There has to be a modifier key that would trigger the switch on the keystroke release event - you can assign this shortcut to something like `Alt+Mouse 5` or `Ctrl+Mouse 5`, and it will do the job.